# jQuery on update event handlers aren't working and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple calculator for rent arrears, so that as soon as the user types in their values, the "results" section of the table will auto-fill with their results.

At the moment when the user fills in their details, the results section just remains as it was before; however when I de-bug the code, it tells me that there are no errors. I'm pretty sure that the problem is in my event handlers, but I can't work out where/why.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#date1").datepicker({

    }).on("change", function (e) {
        dataBind();
    });

    $("#date2").datepicker({

    }).on("change", function (e) {
        dataBind();
    });

    $(document).on("change", "table input", function () {
        dataBind();
    });

    $("#r1").click(function () {
        dataBind();
    });
    $("#r2").click(function () {
        dataBind();
    });
    $("#r3").click(function () {
        dataBind();
    });
});
```

Where date1 and date2 are datepickers, and r1, r2, and r3 are radio buttons.
dataBind is a function which carries out the calculations and updates the results field:

```
var dataBind = function () {

    var config = {
        dueDate: new Date($('#date1').val()),
        untilDate: new Date($('#date2').val()),
        rentAmount: $('#rentAmount').val(),
        dueDateResult: $('#date1'),
        calcUntilResult: $('#date2')
    };
    t = new workings(config);


    $("#dueDateFirstMissed").html(t.dueDateFirstPaymentResult);
    $("#untilDateCalculate").html((t.calculatedUntil));
    $("#numberDays").html(t.numberDays.toFixed(0));
    $("#numberperiods").html((t.numberPeriods));
    $("#amountDue").html("£" + (t.amountDue.toFixed(2)));
    $("#dailyRate").html("£" + ((t.dailyRate).toFixed(2)));
};
```

Here is a link to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezjp20/ak5hexnx/27/) although bear in mind that I haven't finished writing the calculations!

Any help/pointers would be so gratefully appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSFiddle, you have a typo in your `getNumberPeriods` function, where `firsyDate.getMonth()` should be `firstDate.getMonth()`. Rectifying this seems to resolve the issue.

As a sidenote, I would also keep in mind the possibility that someone enter a value that isn't a number in your "Amount of rent due" field. Doing so currently yields `NaN` in your UI.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Julian! How annoying I spent so long trying to figure that out and it was a typo! hahaha. Thanks for the extra tip :)

Comment: @Zehrazjp20 No worries, happy to help! Be sure to make use of your developer console (`Ctrl+Shift+I` in Chrome) to pick up on these types of minor issues - it'll often give you a descriptive error that will help you resolve the issue immediately. Keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

There was a **syntax error** in your variable assigned in below `function`

```
function getNumberPeriods() {
        var periodLength = getPeriodLength();
        var calcDate = (options.untilDate);
        var calcYear = calcDate.getFullYear();
        var calcMonth = calcDate.getMonth();
        var calcDay = calcDate.getDate();
        var firstDate = (options.dueDate);
        var firstYear = firstDate.getFullYear();
        var firstMonth = firstDate.getMonth(); //this was firsyDate.getMonth()
        var firstDay = firstDate.getDate();
        .....
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ak5hexnx/30/)**

---

**UPDATE**

You can change your values when you fill all the 3 fields or else you will get **NaN** in your result and you can do it as below:

```
var dataBind = function () {
    if($("#date1").val()!="" && $("#date2").val()!="" && $('#rentAmount').val()!="") 
    { //If all the fields have values then get it done
    var config = {
        dueDate: new Date($('#date1').val()),
        untilDate: new Date($('#date2').val()),
        rentAmount: $('#rentAmount').val(),
        dueDateResult: $('#date1'),
        calcUntilResult: $('#date2')
    };
    console.log(config);
    t = new workings(config);

    $("#dueDateFirstMissed").html(t.dueDateFirstPaymentResult);
    $("#untilDateCalculate").html((t.calculatedUntil));
    $("#numberDays").html(t.numberDays.toFixed(0));
    $("#numberperiods").html((t.numberPeriods));
    $("#amountDue").html("£" + (t.amountDue.toFixed(2)));
    $("#dailyRate").html("£" + ((t.dailyRate).toFixed(2)));
    }
};
```

> **Note : You haven't given id to your `rentAmount` textbox at top** Just add it too

**[Updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ak5hexnx/35/)**